# Django for template language not working/ rendering any data

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have been working on Django for 2 months now. Before I have retrieved data from the database to the template inside the affiliation app. Now I am trying to render data to another app from views, but the data are not rendered and as well the **for loop** in the django template doesnot display any data. I am feeling the code may be right, but i am not knowing where i am being mistaken.

Below are details:

Views-

```
from affiliation.models import AffProduct

def Sproducts(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user = request.user  # define current user
        resulted = AffProduct.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'onlineshopping.html', { 'resulted': resulted })
```

Urls-

```
path('/', views.onlineshopping, name='onlineshopping'),
path('onlineshopping/', views.Sproducts)
```

HTML-

```
{% for object in resulted %}
<h1>Product Title:{{ object.product_title }}</h1>
    <p>Product ID:{{ object.uid }}</p>
    <p>Specification:{{ object.specification }}</p>
    <p>Terms & Condition:{{ object.terms_conditions }}</p>
    <p>Sale Price:Rs.{{ object.sale_price }}</p>
    <p>Discount:{{ object.discount }}%</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Directory-

```
-myblink(Project)
   -affiliation(app1)
       -models.py #Model is saved here 'AffProduct'
   -onlineshopping(app2)
       -views.py #Want to render the details from here to the template
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong name for your loop. Your resulted has the Tempalte name object but you declare with resulted for this rename

```
return render(request, 'onlineshopping.html', { 'object': resulted })
```

to

```
return render(request, 'onlineshopping.html', { 'resulted': resulted })
```

Comment: Its still not rendering. @ViLuWi

Comment: you got data in your table? Try ```print(resulted)``` to see

Comment: yes, i have got multiple entries. with print(resulted) below the query, nothing is shown in the terminal.

Comment: the model where the data are stored is in different app and i am trying to render in another app inside the same project.

Comment: First try to print what data are you getting in resulted!  Try to print(resulted) after this line in your code...  resulted = AffProduct.objects.all()
print(resulted).